# Save position of menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to do is allow our users to save their selection so when they return to our site the item will already be selected. Below is part of the Menu item which is already calling a java function to log the value of their selection.

```
 <select name="stucountry" class="wide2"  id="scntry" onchange="cntryCode()">
            <option value="" text-align:center>SELECT</option>
            <option value="4">AFGHANISTAN</option>
            <option value="4">ALGERIA</option>
            <option value="3">AZERBAIJAN</option>
            <option value="3">ALBANIA</option>
            <option value="3">ARMENIA</option>
            <option value="1">ANDORRA</option>
            <option value="3">ANGOLA</option>
            <option value="1">ARGENTINA</option>
    </select>
```

For example: If user selects ALBANIA, during their first visit and they want it to be their default selection I would like to offer them the ability to do that. The number of items in the actual select list has over 200 items.

I am able to capture the text of the selection using the below, but I have been unsuccessful in using this to set the select object position as a preference.

```
function getCntgrySelect()
{
    var ctrySelected = "";
    var ctrySelected = $('#scntry').find('option:selected').text();
    return ctryCode;
    alert(ctrySelected);    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the last selection of an user you can store it in an cookie. This way it will be stored at client side with no headache of handling these values are server side.

You can use [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this purpose.

You just store the current selected value with a name(say 'lastSelection') and next time check if there is any cookie with name lastSelection. If this cookie is present then just get the value of this cookie and select the option from select list accordingly.

Comment: My coworker used this and the HTML5 Local storage to complete this. Thanks and sorry it took so long to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using text just use value to save at server.

Save `$("#scntry").val();` to server

and then user `$("#scntry").val(serverreply);` to set back as this will help you save by id not by value and will be faster.

otherwise youn have to use one of the following which works for your jquery version

```
function setCntgrySelect()
{

    var ctrySelected = $('#scntry').find('option[text="SERVERREPLY"]').val();
    $('#scntry').val(ctrySelected )

}
```

OR

```
 function setCntgrySelect()
    {

        var ctrySelected = $('#scntry option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "SERVERREPLY"; }).val();
        $('#scntry').val(ctrySelected )

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should have a look into the localStorage API (see [API-Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)). if i recall correctly it's available past IE8. With prototypes you may ofc implement backwards compatability. Basically you would handle your page load like this:

```
var preselect = localStorage.getItem("valueKeyForSelector");
selectCheckboxValue(preselect);
```

while modifying your changed method to update the local storage. that way the selection is persisted through serperate page visits.

I hope that's what you were looking for.